# Binding to Property of a ComboBox's SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox, selecteditem

I am having a hard time finding the right syntax for binding to a ComboBox's SelectedItem's property. This is the XAML I am trying to use for the binding. Where you see SelectedItem.Mode is the idea I am having difficulty with. Note that CurrentMode is in the ViewModel and has the same type as SelectedItem.Mode

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem.Mode="{Binding Path=CurrentMode, Mode=TwoWays}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <local:ModeItem Mode="Free" ImageSource="pencil.png"/>
            <local:ModeItem Mode="Arrow" ImageSource="arrow.png"/>

        </ComboBox>
```

A local:ModeItem looks like this

```
    public class ModeItem : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Mode", typeof(AnnotationMode), typeof(ModeItem));
    public AnnotationMode Mode
    {
        get { return (AnnotationMode)GetValue(ModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModeProperty, value); }
    }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I am using MVVM and trying to bind the AnnotationMode (CurrentMode) of the ViewModel to that of the ComboBox's SelectedItem's AnnotationMode (Mode)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this 
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMode}

You don't have to do all this extra stuff you are doing. Note You do need to make the datacontext of the combobox is pointing to your viewmodel.

Edit :- 
You should be able to do this

```
SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentMode, Mode=TwoWay}" 
SelectedValuePath="Mode"
```

Comment: But won't that just try to bind SelectedItem (of type local:ModeItem) to CurrentMode (of type AnnotationMode) ? Will that work? And thanks, but no worries the datacontext is loaded.

Comment: Is this code you have control over, because if it is why not just create a property of the type you are trying to have binding work with. Why would you want to complicate matters with subclassing in xaml? Note you are right about what would happen with what I have an answer.